# How to pick a key and its appropriate value in .txt file in java

Tags: java, hashmap

This is my following .txt file

[.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDsrM.png)

I want to retrieve IP address based on URl.I have tried the following code but it got failed.Can i do it using Hashmap. This is my first post.I apologize for my mistakes.

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

```
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:/Users/charan/Desktop/Resources/HashCheck.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter:");
    String output = in.next();
    String line;

    while((line =  br.readLine()) != null){
        if (line.contains(output))
        {
            output = line.split(":")[1].trim();
            System.out.println(output);
            break;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("UrL not found");
        break;
    }
    in.close();

}}
```

Comment: you want to remove the bottom break, else it will break on the first iteration (first line).  If you had debugged this you could see this easily.

Comment: @Nuthann98 Did you mean to have a block `{ ... }` around the `else` with `break` inside that block? You have a floating `}` close brace at the end

Comment: @Nic Why would that help?  It would still mean that it will break on the first iteration - Oh I see, you are saying the code doesn't even compile?

Comment: Yes there is an extra close brace

Comment: @Nuthann92 Did Scary Wombat's suggestion solve your problem?

Comment: Your code has worked .Thank you so much @Pankaj Singhal

Comment: Thanks for suggestions @Scary Wombat

Comment: Thanks for suggestions  @Nic

Comment: @Nuthann92 can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:/Users/charan/Desktop/Resources/HashCheck.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter:");
    String output = in.next();
    String line;
    String myIp = null;                       //assign a new variable to put IP into
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains(output)) {
            myIp = line.split(":")[1].trim(); //assign IP to the new variable
            System.out.println(myIp);
            break;                            //break only if you get the IP. else let it iterate over all the elements.
        }
    }
    in.close();
    if (myIp == null) {                      //if the new variable is still null, IP is not found
        System.out.println("UrL not found");
    }
}
```